# How to add multiple cookies to Response in WCF / REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies

I have access to `WebOperationContext` and can add one cookie by doing this:

```
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a");
```

However if I call that several times, e.g.:

```
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a");
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie: foo_b=bar_b");
```

I should get the following in my header (2 cookies):

```
Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a
Set-Cookie: foo_b=bar_b
```

But instead get:

```
Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a, foo_b=bar_b
```

How do I set multiple cookies? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the cookies can be set on one Set-Cookie: header line, but you will need to place a ';' semicolon at the end of the cookie...

```
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a;," 
                                                           + foo_b=bar_b;");
```

then the result will be: (which browser consider to be 2 cookies not just 1)

```
Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a;, foo_b=bar_b;
// browser sees this as 2 cookies: `foo_a` & `foo_b`
```

as opposed to

```
Set-Cookie: foo_a=bar_a, foo_b=bar_b
// browser sees this as 1 cookie: `foo_a` with value: `=bar_a, foo_b=bar_b`
```

Comment: Is the comma necessary? I have similar output but it just has a semicolon and no comma. Are you aware of any compatibility issues that might cause?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie` instead.

Comment: this is for asp.net, not wcf (I think)