# Return CookieContainer from WCF to Client(Windows Phone7.1)

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7.1

I am new in WCF. I don't know how  to return CookieContainer  object from wcf service to client i.e. windows phone 7.1.

I have two solution

Test(Windows phone), WcfService1

How can I return CookieContainer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/26935056-c4dc-4764-b1d3-38893ea53026/

or here:

[How to add multiple cookies to Response in WCF / REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444022/how-to-add-multiple-cookies-to-response-in-wcf-rest-service)

You don't return CookieContainer, just set cookie header in response.
WCF client will parse these cookies and add them to it's CookieContainer.

Comment: so I can't return cookiescontainer.

Comment: In my project I must require CookieContainer